# Unable to install Strapi on a Windows localhost with MySQL

Tags: mysql, installation, localhost, strapi

I'm trying to install Strapi on my Windows 10 machine. I used XAMPP to install Apache and MySQL and have verified via phpMyAdmin that the localhost connection is working and I can access the MySQL DB.

During the Strapi installation process, I receive the error message ***"Installing dependencies: info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying..."***. I don't understand why I'm getting this error message and don't know where to look (outside of validating that phpMyAdmin can, indeed, connect to the localhost MySQL DB.) I have removed and reinstalled XAMPP, rebooted the computer to no avail.

Any and all help most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. My Norton firewall was getting in the way. I disabled it and was then able to successfully install Strapi.